# Probability theory question

Tags: probability, statistics

Can someone maybe explain this question that I had on my exam?

> A pharmaceutical company uses a very controlled production process
>   that fails for only 1 out of 10000 pills it produces. On top of that
>   it has an optical checking process to find these faulty pills. It
>   classifies each pill as "good" or " faulty" correctly 99.9% of the
>   time. What is the probability that there really is a problem with the
>   pill every time that the checking process declares a pill faulty?

I used Bayes' theorem, but couldn't find all the probabilities needed to complete this calculation. How should I have approached this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, to be migrated to math SE, since this deals with the application of probability theory to pharmaceuticals and is devoid of physics content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The machine gets it right 99.9% of the time. When it has checked 10,000 pills, it will have identified 10 bad ones - wrongly.

In reality, only 1 in 10,000 pills is bad. Of the 10, there is only 1 bad. The probability that there really is a problem with the pill is 10% (or if you say "it found 10 pills that weren't really bad, and the one pill that really was bad", then the probability is 9% - 1 in 11).

This is the problem with any kind of screening for a rare event - your screening method will almost always throw a LOT of false positives. The math behind this is really important for things like breast cancer screening... it's why so many women end up going to biopsy etc, but are found not to have cancer.

Comment: It's too bad that companies who use this method don't use a second scanner to look at the "bad" pills before any pills are discarded.  Of course, I realize that this is an economic problem, as saving 10 pills out of 10000 is probably not going to make up for the capital and operating expense of a second scanner.

Comment: @DavidWhite it depends on whether the "find a bad pill" event is due to the design of the scanner, or some random occurrence. If it's random, then you could just run the pills through the scanner multiple times and improve your yield. If it's due to the design, then you would need a different kind of test to distinguish things (like the biopsy, ultrasound or MRI in mammography; you don't just take another 2D image unless it's with a different view, etc).

Comment: That's a good point, @Floris.

Comment: that's the strategy we used to take in testing inkjet printheads. at the end of the production line, each head was print-tested, and each failed head was retested up to 4 times in succession to eliminate false negatives.

Comment: @nielsnielsen - yeah, I knew of a place where a certain metric in final testing had to be "< 11". When it failed, it would be retested up to three times. If you looked at the histogram of values, it looked like a Gaussian centered around 10.5, with a big spike at 10.9 and nothing above that - they would re-test until it "just passed" due to some normal random fluctuation. They are not in business any more.

Comment: This very effect- "test it until it passes"- is exactly why an Alaska Airlines DC9 crashed into the pacific near catalina island some years ago. the electric jackscrew drive which furnishes primary pitch trim control on that plane was, upon inspection, found to be right at the end-of-life wear limit, and was repeatedly tested until it wasn't, and was then returned to service as "within limits". the remains of the drive shaft-and-ballscrew assembly were later fished off the bottom of the ocean and found to have catastrophically failed due to excessive wear.

Comment: @Floris, ever considered writing a book full of cautionary tales like that?

Comment: @nielsnielsen oh boy, it would be a big book...

Comment: where did you work?

Answer (score 3):

The question is a bit vague in how the optical test is described. Normally you would define a sensitivity (fraction of all positives that are positively identified) and specificity (fraction of positively identified that are in fact positives). I assume that the question means "99.9% sensitivity and 99.9% specificity".

You can now think of it in terms of fractions.
The 1 fault will likely be identified (99.9% sensitivity), but of the remaining 9999 samples $9999\cdot(1-0.999) = 9.99$ will be falsely identified. This gives us more or less 11 pills of which only 1 is faulty, or 1/11 = 9%.

Or in math with Bayes theorem, H being hypothesis, E being event (detection):
$$
P(H|E) = \frac{P(E|H)\cdot P(H)}{P(E)}\\
=\frac{P(E|H)\cdot P(H)}{P(H)\cdot P(E|H) + P(-H)\cdot P(E|-H)}\\
=\frac{.999 \cdot  .0001}{.0001\cdot .999 + .9999\cdot .001}\\
=0.09
$$

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R13BD8qKeTg&t=64s